# Uses of Java Native Interface(JNI)

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

Could you please help me understanding under what scenario JNI (or Java Native Interface) could be useful from web application development perspective?

I did read some articles that promises that JNI can give you access to native application like menu bar/scroll bar etc, so the user interface can be more catchy... however these things can be done in other technologies rather than Java.

I'm still not able to find practical uses of JNI. Have you used the JNI in your projects/apps ever? and for what?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI#Purpose_and_features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary for web development since just about anything you need is already written in Java--and it would also be a terrible idea because it will make your app platform dependent.

It is sometimes used to access a system API an old DLL that you must use without rewriting for some awful management-related reason.

Comment: Or because the underlying library is massive and rewriting it would be a multi-year feat of engineering...

Comment: @sjr That's the usual awful management-related reason.  Most developers would understand that rewriting it would give you a better integrated more stable, simpler solution in a fraction of the original time, it would cut maintenance costs and improve agility/ability to add features.  Managers don't usually get that throwing it all away is often the best way to move forward.

Comment: If most developers understand it that way, then they are incorrect. Having two implementations of the same library is a huge burden. Even before you get there,  for most libraries of any significant size it is infeasible to rewrite it in any reasonable time.

Comment: @sjr Why would you have two versions?  I wasn't suggesting that.  Generally you encounter this kind of problem with porting and using legacy stuff.  Why would you support both versions?  If you want to ship for multiple platforms, just port it to java and throw the legacy version in the dumpster. Remember it's web and a web portion written in a language that uses JNI is problematic to begin with (there is a reason web servers aren't usually written in C)

Comment: Well, in my experience you want to use the existing library precisely because it's *not* legacy, it is in fact in wide use and under heavy development. Why duplicate the development effort?

Comment: Can you name a few libraries that would be used for a Java web-server and require JNI?  It's not really my area of expertise, but I really wouldn't think this would be a great idea...  Maybe for a client app..

Answer (score 4):

JNI is useful if you need to call some lower level language (C, C++, assembler) function from within Java. Many projects use JNI, for example:

- JOGL (Java library for making calls to OpenGL, a C library)
- SWT (Java UI library that uses JNI to call a native windowing library, for example GTK on Linux)

There are utilities to automatically generate JNI code, like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which can dramatically ease the pain of generating JNI wrapper code (which involves writing a bit of Java and some of the underlying language).

Comment: As it is shown here, JNI can be used to obtain better performnace results or so as not to rewrite libraries from another language. The main disadvantage is that with JNI, the program may be machine-dependent.